# Fill out empty spaces with underscore

Tags: c++

I have a telegram that i have to send to the PLC, 1 substring of that telegram provides the barcodeID. It has 6 spaces and it starts with 1 and it is counting up.

For the PLC to work i have to fill up to empty spots wit an underscore. F.E.

_____1
____22
___333

Is there a way i can fix this?

I know that i can fill up the empty spaces with zero's like this: %06d

000001
000022
000333

```
gLog.LogPrintf(Info, "customerlog", "Storage Out Ready: %02d%02d%02d%s%04d%010d%02d%010d%010d%06d%06d%06d%06d%06d%06d%010d",
        (*inMessage)["sender"].asInt(), (*inMessage)["reciever"].asInt(), (*inMessage)["series"].asInt(), (*inMessage)["type"].asString().c_str(),
        (*inMessage)["command"].asInt(), (*inMessage)["id"].asInt(), (*inMessage)["priority"].asInt(), (*inMessage)["source"].asInt(),
        (*inMessage)["target"].asInt(), (*inMessage)["height"].asInt(), (*inMessage)["width"].asInt(), (*inMessage)["length"].asInt(),
        (*inMessage)["weight"].asInt(), (*inMessage)["status"].asInt(), (*inMessage)["error"].asInt(), (*inMessage)["data"].asInt());
        gLog.LogPrintf(Info, "Barcode ID: ", (*inMessage)["id"].asCString());
        gLog.LogPrintf(Info, "error: ", (*inMessage)["error"].asInt());
```

Comment: Append the id to a string of 6 underscores. Then take the last 6 characters, using e.g. `substr()`

Comment: What is a "PLC"? What is `glog`?

Comment: @Steve: That's very inefficient. Also let's avoid giving answers in the comments section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to go the C way, you can do it [like this](http://cpp.sh/2r6mo):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  const char *padding = "______";
  int n = 123;
  char buf[7];
  int len;
  len = snprintf(buf, 7, "%d", n);
  printf("%.*s%s", 6 - std::min(6, len), padding, buf);
}
```

Output:

```
___123
```

If the number has more than 6 digits, it will be truncated by taking only the 6 leftmost digits. For example, if `n` is `1234567890`, the output will be `123456`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use the standard library, you can use the formatting capabilities it provides. Here a mini demo of that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

#define BUFFER_SIZE (10)
int main() {
  std::stringstream buffer;
  buffer << std::right << std::setw(BUFFER_SIZE) << std::setfill('_') << 1;
  std::cout << buffer.str() << std::endl;
  buffer.str(std::string());
  buffer << std::right << std::setw(BUFFER_SIZE) << std::setfill('_') << 1234;
  std::cout << buffer.str() << std::endl;
  buffer.str(std::string());
  buffer << std::right << std::setw(BUFFER_SIZE) << std::setfill('_') << 1234567;
  std::cout << buffer.str() << std::endl;
  buffer.str(std::string());
  return 0;
}
```

std::right makes the formatting to align to right, std::setfill sets '_' as padding character and std::setw sets the width required.
Best regards.